# F# project with typeprovider using dotnet-core in linux, FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll error

Tags: linux, f#, .net-core

I am trying to create a dotnet-core F# project with FSharp.Data (the standard typeprovider library) as dependency under linux.

I've created a project using the command `dotnet new -l F#` and added `FSharp.Data` as dependency.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "compilerName": "fsc",
    "compile": {
      "includeFiles": [
        "Program.fs"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.netcore": "1.0.0-alpha-160316",
    "FSharp.Data": {"version": "2.3.1"},
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "dotnet-compile-fsc": {
      "version": "1.0.0-*",
      "imports": [
        "dnxcore50",
        "portable-net45+win81",
        "netstandard1.3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "imports": [
        "portable-net45+win8",
        "dnxcore50"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I try to build the project (by executing `dotnet restore` followed by `dotnet build`) I get an error which I think can be boiled down to `Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Data.DesignTime....`

```
Project fsharp2 (.NETStandard,Version=v1.5) will be compiled because inputs were modified
Compiling fsharp2 for .NETStandard,Version=v1.5
/home/michel/dotnet/dotnet compile-fsc @/home/michel/Documents/DOTNET/fsharp2/obj/Debug/netstandard1.5/dotnet-compile.rsp returned Exit Code 1
/home/michel/Documents/DOTNET/fsharp2/error FS3031: The type provider '/home/michel/.nuget/packages/FSharp.Data/2.3.1/lib/portable-net45+netcore45/FSharp.Data.dll' reported an error: Assembly attribute 'TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute' refers to a designer assembly 'FSharp.Data.DesignTime' which cannot be loaded or doesn't exist. Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Data.DesignTime, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
/home/michel/Documents/DOTNET/fsharp2/warning FS3005: Referenced assembly '/home/michel/.nuget/packages/FSharp.Data/2.3.1/lib/portable-net45+netcore45/FSharp.Data.dll' has assembly level attribute 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute' but no public type provider classes were found

Compilation failed.
    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time elapsed 00:00:05.0221430
```

I've checked that there do exist a `FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll` file under the `.nuget/packages/FSharp.Data/2.3.1/lib/portable-net45+netcore45/` directory. dotnet-core also works perfectly fine for a simple hello world program with no extra dependencies added.

**How can I successfully add FSharp.Data as a dependency in my dotnet-core project?**

Comment: [I have reported this on the CLI repo.](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3776)

Comment: This problem I had in a different context. I just added the FSharp.Data.DesignTime.dll explicitly to my project. I think it will work if you do the same and add it to dependencies explicitly.